# free ipad emulator for windows

Tags: ios-simulator, ipa

Is there any free iPad emulator for windows available?
(for stand alone apps, not for webpages)

thanks!

raul bada

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you'll need an Intel based Mac for an iPad or any other iOS emulator.

Comment: Chris Kent that is not true there are many iPad emulators online however as far as i know there are non that are truly connectable to iTunes they seems to of coded a copy of application store and iTunes so most of the things you wish to do cannot be done sorry.